# Yii2: Remove "(not set)" in GridView and DetailView for null values

Tags: gridview, view, yii2, detailview

How can I remove or replace strings `(not set)` in my GridView and ListView?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Two ways that I know (now):

**Formatter**

Set [nullDisplay of Formatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-i18n-formatter.html#$nullDisplay-detail) to something other than null. You can do this in global configuration or for the single GridView or DetailView.

Globally (typically in `config/web.php` or `<application>/config/main.php` files):

```php
'components' => [
    ...
    'formatter' => [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
        'nullDisplay' => '',
    ],
    ...
],
```

In certain GridView (same with DetailView):

```php
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $myProvider,
    'formatter' => ['class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter','nullDisplay' => ''],
    'columns'      => [
        ...
    ],
]); ?>
```

**Set the value**

Probably not so elegant. In a certain GridView:

```php
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $myProvider,
    'columns'      => [
        ...
        [
            'attribute' => 'some_attribute',
            'format'    => 'raw',
            'value'     => function (ModelClass $model) {
                if ($model->some_attribute != null) {
                    return $model->some_attribute; 
              //or: return Html::encode($model->some_attribute)
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            },
        ],
        ...
    ],
]); ?>
```

Or in a certain DetailView:

```php
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model'      => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        ...
        [
            'attribute' => 'some_attribute',
            'value' => $model->some_attribute != null ? $model->some_attribute : '', 
      //or: 'value' => $model->some_attribute != null ? Html::encode($model->some_attribute) : '',
        ],
        ...
    ],
]) ?>
```

**Two hints**

If several approaches are used at the same time: setting the value (directly or by function) overrides the formatter configuration of the Grid/DetailView, and this in turn overrides a global formatter configuration.

You can also define something different than an empty string. E.g. if bootstrap is used you may want to use `\yii\bootstrap\Html::icon('question-sign')` (or `'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>'`) to get a symbol for missing values.

Comment: Ok but consider using `$attribute !== null` or similar instead of `!= null`.

Answer (score 10):

use this:

```
use Yii;

...

Yii::$app->formatter->nullDisplay = 'N\A';
```

Answer (score 1):

Set emptycell in gridview config:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
  'emptyCell'=>'-',
  'columns' => [
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
.........
      ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
  ],
 ]); ?>
```

or in :

```
  'attribute' => 'description',
  'label' => Yii::t('app', 'description'),
  'value' => function($data) {
         return !empty($data->description) ? $data->description : '-';
   }
```

Comment: This is not the right. As documentation says emptyCell is to show when nothing is returned.

Answer (score 1):

for `kartik\grid\GridView`;

```
'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
'attribute'=>'myAttribute',
'header' => 'myHeader',                                            
'editableOptions' => [                         
    'inputType' => \kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
    'valueIfNull' => '-',

/**
 * @var string the value to be displayed. If not set, this will default to the attribute value. If the attribute
 * value is null, then this will display the value as set in [[valueIfNull]].
 */
public $displayValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

For DetailView and GridView I use if else in columns

DetailView:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
   'model' => $model,
   'attributes' => [
      ['label' => 'labelName', 'value' => function($data) {
         if (!empty($data->tDeal->DealDate)) { 
            return $data->tDeal->DealDate; 
         } else { return ''; }
      }],
    ],
])
?>
```

GridView:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'columns' => [
      ['label' => 'labelName', 'value' => function($data) {
         if (!empty($data->tDeal->DealDate)) { 
            return $data->tDeal->DealDate; 
         } else { return ''; }
      }],
    ],
])
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

I wouldnt recommend set nullDisplay method. It is best practical to check if the variable you access is null or not.

I would do

```php
//model code
public function getProjectName()
{
    $project = $this->project;
    return ($project) ? $project->name : '';
}

//your gridview
<?= GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $myProvider,
'columns'      => [
    ...
    [
        'attribute' => 'some_attribute',
        'format'    => 'raw',
        'value'     => function (ModelClass $model) {
             $model->projectName;
        },
    ],
    ...
],
 ]); ?>
```

Comment: Why is checking each item to null is better than setting formatter to null. Explain